# How to data-autocomplete from a list of models pass to the view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a question: I work with MVC an Web API and I want to use 'data-autocomplete' option for an 'input', but I don't want to get the data with '@Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName);' , I want to get the data from the view, as a list of models pass from the controller.
Like this `@model List<Project_2.Models.CartiModels>`, and I don't want to autocomplete the input like this : `data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("method", "controller")"`.

That is because I want the list loaded into the view at the first page load and be there, not generate itself every time that the client introduce another value into a textbox.

Please help me! Thank you

Comment: Are you building your views with ASP.NET MVC or another front end framework?

Comment: I am building my view with MVC. Just the part with db connection is in  another project(WEb API), but the views are created in the same project (with MVC)

Comment: Are you using JQuery UI to find inputs with 'data-autocomplete' and use this attribute value for the URL to call for autocompletion? (like this http://mvc3notes.blogspot.fr/2013/02/jquery-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Your view you can do it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Assign your list to Jquery variable
         var list = @Model.Name; 
    }    

$(".txtAutocomplete").autocomplete({
    // Specify the source as the jquery variable
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.each(list, function (index, item) { // Iterate through your list
                itemList.push({ label: item.PropertyName, value: item.PropertyName2 });
        });
        response(itemList);
    },
    ..... 
 </script>
```